# Calculating a Jordan Basis for a matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I am trying to calculate a Jordan basis for the matrix A.
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\chi(A)=(\lambda-2)^2 \to \lambda =2 , \alpha =2$$
$$V(2)=ker(A-2I)= span\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
In my understanding to find the other basis vector, one chooses $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and computes $Bv \ne 0 , B=A-2I$, which will give the other vector in the Jordan basis of A. However I get the zero matrix in this case, I also tried to compute $ker(A-2I)^2$ but $(A-2I)^2$ is also the zero matrix.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a vector $w$ which is not in $\ker(A-2I)$, say $w = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1}$ and define $v = (A-2I)w = \pmatrix{1 \\ 1}$.

Then $v \in \ker(A-2I)$ so $$Av = 2v, \quad Aw = (A-2I)w +2w = v + 2w$$
which means that with respect to the basis $\{v,w\}$ the operator $A$ has matrix
$$\pmatrix{2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2}.$$

Comment: Did you mean $v=(A-2I)w$, if this is the case I essentially just compute $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}= (A-2I)w$?

Comment: @benmcgloin Yes, of course. We could have started from any other $w \notin \ker (A-2I)$.